# Does `par` create another thread?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, parallel-processing, multicore

My understanding to `par` is that it will create a thread in another core to execution.

But I failed proof this understanding with following test code since the result showing seems only one thread is running.

Could you help me to figure out what's wrong here?

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Concurrent
import System.IO.Unsafe

fib :: Int -> Int 
fib 0 = 1 
fib 1 = 1 
fib n = (fib (n-1)) + (fib (n - 2))

test :: String -> [Int] -> IO () 
test _ [] = return () 
test name (a:xs) = do 
    tid <- myThreadId 
    print $ (show tid) ++ "==>" ++ (show a) ++ "==>" ++ (show $ fib a) ++ "==>" ++ name
    x `par` y 
  where x = test "2" xs
        y = test "3" (tail xs)

main = test "1" [10..35]
```

Compiled with:

```
ghc --make -threaded -rtsopts test-par.hs
time ./test-par +RTS -N2
```

The result

```
"ThreadId 3==>10==>89==>1"
"ThreadId 3==>12==>233==>3"
"ThreadId 3==>14==>610==>3"
"ThreadId 3==>16==>1597==>3"
"ThreadId 3==>18==>4181==>3"
"ThreadId 3==>20==>10946==>3"
"ThreadId 3==>22==>28657==>3"
"ThreadId 3==>24==>75025==>3"
"ThreadId 3==>26==>196418==>3"
"ThreadId 3==>28==>514229==>3"
"ThreadId 3==>30==>1346269==>3"
"ThreadId 3==>32==>3524578==>3"
"ThreadId 3==>34==>9227465==>3"

real    0m1.131s
user    0m0.668s
sys 0m0.492s
```

How many core I have?

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l
2
```

-------------------------------- update

I think [this paper by Simon Marlow](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/threadscope.pdf) is a good reference for such newbie question.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/958449/83805

Comment: Somewhat relevant - Simon Peyton-Jones has emphasized, in a video presentation (possibly YOW! 2011 related, possibly on Channel 9) emphasized that `par` is very lightweight and doesn't have the same setup costs as a thread or process. I'll post a link if I can figure out which video it was. At the time, my first thought was "implicit thread pool".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, `par` does not guarantee to create another thread.

It registers a *spark* in the runtime, which *may* cause the computation to be executed in a different thread, depending on the dynamic workload of the machine.

Creating a spark is very cheap, so you can create many (1000x) more than you have threads, and the runtime will just try to keep all your cores busy.

In your case, your `x` computation is registered as a spark, and then immediately discarded (you never refer to it again). So the garbage collector can remove it.

To parallelize a recursive function, you'll typically want to just use `par` up to some depth.

An example -- a recursive function with a cutoff depth:

```
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Monad
import Text.Printf

cutoff = 35

fib' :: Int -> Integer
fib' 0 = 0
fib' 1 = 1
fib' n = fib' (n-1) + fib' (n-2)

fib :: Int -> Integer
fib n | n < cutoff = fib' n
      | otherwise  = r `par` (l `pseq` l + r)
 where
    l = fib (n-1)
    r = fib (n-2)

main = forM_ [0..45] $ \i ->
            printf "n=%d => %d\n" i (fib i)
```

Run as:

```
$ ghc -O2 -threaded --make A.hs -rtsopts -fforce-recomp
$ ./A +RTS -N16 -s
```

Yields a parallel workload 1248.9% over sequential (i.e. 12.48x):

```
                                   Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      6264 colls,  6263 par    5.23s    0.41s     0.0001s    0.0109s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     1 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0002s    0.0002s

  Parallel GC work balance: 7.09 (1797194 / 253525, ideal 16)

                        MUT time (elapsed)       GC time  (elapsed)
  Task  0 (worker) :    7.56s    (  9.36s)       0.92s    (  0.89s)
  Task  1 (worker) :    0.12s    ( 10.21s)       0.02s    (  0.05s)
  Task  2 (bound)  :    8.39s    (  9.51s)       0.70s    (  0.74s)
  Task  3 (worker) :    0.00s    (  0.00s)       0.00s    (  0.00s)
  Task  4 (worker) :    7.17s    (  9.60s)       0.53s    (  0.66s)
  Task  5 (worker) :    7.28s    (  9.55s)       0.56s    (  0.71s)
  Task  6 (worker) :    7.48s    (  9.52s)       0.56s    (  0.74s)
  Task  7 (worker) :    7.11s    (  9.54s)       0.66s    (  0.72s)
  Task  8 (worker) :    7.41s    (  9.62s)       0.70s    (  0.64s)
  Task  9 (worker) :    7.69s    (  9.48s)       0.66s    (  0.78s)
  Task 10 (worker) :    7.56s    (  9.51s)       0.56s    (  0.75s)
  Task 11 (worker) :    7.69s    (  9.42s)       0.86s    (  0.84s)
  Task 12 (worker) :    7.42s    (  9.40s)       0.92s    (  0.86s)
  Task 13 (worker) :    7.28s    (  9.39s)       0.91s    (  0.86s)
  Task 14 (worker) :    7.44s    (  9.38s)       0.91s    (  0.87s)
  Task 15 (worker) :    7.25s    (  9.33s)       1.11s    (  0.93s)
  Task 16 (worker) :    7.94s    (  9.33s)       0.97s    (  0.93s)
  Task 17 (worker) :    7.59s    (  9.37s)       1.06s    (  0.88s)

  SPARKS: 597 (446 converted, 0 dud, 1 GC'd, 150 fizzled)

  Productivity  96.1% of total user, 1245.3% of total elapsed
```

We created 597 sparks, of which 446 were converted into threads.

If you explicitly want to do manual thread creation and communication, this can be done via `forkIO` and `MVars`.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that `par` only works for pure computations, so doing `par a b` where `a` and `b` are monadic actions will in fact just discard the `a` action and perform the `b` action, which is what is happening in the askers example code.

Comment: Well, it 'works' for monadic actions in that they are put in a queue, evaluated to their WHNF (e.g. `IO ()`) and returned. They're not executed though for their effect.  Same as putting a function in a spark.

Comment: 1. Since whether thread will be created or is "depending on the dynamic workload of the machine.", am I able to figure out it whether it is created or via any tools? Otherwise, is it not a very meaningful  thing we should concern about?

Comment: 2. Seem IO action seems be discard even I change to `par x (pseq y (x >> y >> print1))`. Any samples show scenario that "it works for monadic when in a queue", or any references?

Comment: The gc stats (above) show you when you're creating too many sparks. For more thorough debugging, use threadscope: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ThreadScope

Comment: Damn, what kind of beast of a machine have they given you there at your new job? It's nice to have someone who's got access to hardware with high levels of concurrency, and the willingness to help everyone so enthusiastically.