# Parallel recursive tasks in a threadpool

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

My exact example is parallelizing this tree aggregation, where the information flows from the leaves to the root :

```
aggregate :: ([a] -> a) -> Tree a -> Tree a
aggregate _ (Node x []) = Node x []
aggregate aggregator (Node _ children) =
  let agChildren = map (aggregate aggregator) children in
  Node (aggregator $ map (\(Node y _) -> y) agChildren) agChildren
```

I'd like each application of the aggregator function to be processed on a different thread. So I imagine altering the code above so that it spawns a tree of dependent tasks and gives them to a thread pool.

I don't want a thread affected at a node, waiting for children threads to complete. Instead, this waiting thread should go compute other available children in the tree. Also it would be too slow to run a thread for each node concurrently. My trees can have hundreds of nodes and my machine only has 8 cores : they would spend their time scheduling instead of calculating. I need a thread pool that consumes tasks only when other tasks finish.

As mentionned by ErikR below, `parMap` seems to do exactly that. I tried it and executed it with strat 64 +RTS -N2, to get exactly the same computation time. Here is the code (that does an idiotic computation just to test the performance), do you understand why the time doesn't change ?

```
slowAggregate :: [Int] -> Int
slowAggregate l = let s = sum l in
  sum [a + b + c | a <- [0..s], b <- [0..s], c <- [0..s] ]

bigTree :: Tree Int
bigTree = Node 0 $ map (\x -> Node x []) [71..78]

aggregate :: NFData a => ([a] -> a) -> Tree a -> Tree a
aggregate _ (Node x []) = Node x []
aggregate aggregator (Node _ children) =
  let agChildren = parMap rdeepseq (aggregate aggregator) children in 
  Node (aggregator $ map (\(Node y _) -> y) agChildren) agChildren

main = timeIt $ let (Node y _) = aggregate slowAggregate bigTree in print y
```

Comment: btw - the book ["Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell"](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/pcph/) is an excellent book on this subject.

Comment: I've read this chapter already : http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch03.html. Nowhere do we specify the thread count to strategies, so I imagine they go to a thread pool. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Have a look at [Data Parallel Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parallel runtime already manages a thread pool for sparks.
From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/959001/866915):

> Sparks are not threads. forkIO introduces Haskell threads (which map down onto fewer real OS threads). Sparks create entries in the work queues for each thread, from which they'll take tasks to execute if the thread becomes idle.

So I would first just try using `parMap strat` and see if it works for you.

In fact, if your tree is a Traversable, I'd look at using `parTraversable`:

```
parTraversable :: Traversable t => Strategy a -> Strategy (t a)
```

Comment: I tried `parMap` and updated the question. It slows down !

Comment: For your example tree and aggregator sparking every call to aggregate is not the best granularity of parallelism. You might see a speed up for a different aggregator function. ie one that does more work. Or if you used `parListChunk`.

Comment: No luck with either parListChunk or a longer aggregator (updated in the question above).

Comment: I answered your original question before you changed it. If you want help with a specific computation, please post it as a new question and I can devote more time to examining that case.

Comment: And I thank you for you answer, I just accepted it. I inserted a 0 node in between to get some recursion, which yields : SPARKS: 16 (7 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 9 fizzled). Still no time improvement with 8 cores though. If I post this as another question, won't it be flagged as duplicate ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `slowAggregate` example the function `slowAggregate` only gets called once - for the top node.

It does not get called for any of the child nodes because those nodes don't have any children themselves. Those nodes are handled by the first guard clause of `aggregate`:

```
aggregate _ (Node x []) = Node x []
```

Moreover, when I ran the program with `+RTS -s -N2` all 8 of the sparks that were created fizzled:

```
  SPARKS: 8 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 8 fizzled)
```

These sparks correspond to the 8 elements in the list [71..78]. All of these fizzled because none of them called `slowAggregate`.